# selenium get abs url from href attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsoup

when im downloading a page with selenium and process it with java jsoup. I get the hrefs in the source code like this:

`<a href="/f7-technical-trading" class="forumtitle">Technical Trading</a>`

Is there a way to get the absolute url from this or to force selenium to transform it to an absolute url? Updating the links after getting the page doesn't sound like a clean solution.

Comment: Do you mean that you get the whole tag instead of the href attribute?

Comment: I think you have to build the URL yourself by concatenating driver.getCurrentUrl() with the attribute you get from href

Answer (score 0):

If you get the href just with selenium, this works as expected:

```
yourElement.get_attribute('href')
```

This is a quick sample:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # note this is my webdriver
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

url = "https://www.duckduckgo.co.uk"
driver.get(url)

aList = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

for a in aList:
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

Output contains:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/spread
https://duckduckgo.com/spread
https://duckduckgo.com/app
https://duckduckgo.com/app
https://duckduckgo.com/newsletter
https://duckduckgo.com/newsletter
```

This  is how the DOM looks: (it's relative - but gets the full path)

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the tip. Now I will process the replacement with the driver given base-url before the jsoup parsing. Its not the perfect solution, but much better than replacing with external given base-url after parsing.